# Entity Framework: Erro ao Atualizar Objeto

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Não estou conseguindo atualizar meu objeto. Criei o método da seguinte forma:

```
public void Atualizar(T obj)
{
    banco.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
    banco.SaveChanges();
}
```

A seguinte exceção foi lançada:

```
Attaching an entity of type 'ProjetoTeste.Domain.Entities.Clientes.Cliente'
failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary
key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the
state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph
have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and
have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the
'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set
the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.VerifyRootForAdd(Boolean doAttach, String entitySetName, IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, EntityEntry existingEntry, EntitySet& entitySet, Boolean& isNoOperation)
   em System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachTo(String entitySetName, Object entity)
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.c__DisplayClassa.b__9()
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Attach(Object entity)
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.set_State(EntityState value)
   em System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry`1.set_State(EntityState value)
   em ProjetoTeste.Infra.Data.Repositories.RepositoryBase`1.Atualizar(T obj) na D:\Informática\Raphael\Projetos VS2015\ProjetoTeste\Codigo\ProjetoTeste\ProjetoTeste.Data\Repositories\RepositoryBase.cs:linha 18
```

Está falando que está dando conflito de chave, não entendi, pois já que se trata de update e não insert.

No contexto já adicionei o objeto cliente, do qual quero atualizar:

```
public DbSet<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
```

Comment: O erro não está neste trecho de código, provavelmente no método que que chanma o "Atualizar".
O DbContext fica "observando" a entidade que retornou, parece que vc está adicionando uma outra entidade com o mesmo id.

Comment: Obrigado Fernando! Eu vi que o objeto está fora do contexto porque eu estava tentando pegar o objeto do parâmetro e passando para o método atualizar.
Então eu fiz uma gambiarra da seguinte forma: recuperei o objeto que quero atualizar com GetById() e passei os valores do objeto do parâmetro para o objeto que foi retornado pelo GetById() para que o EF não perca a referência.
Existe algum método para adicionar esse objeto ao contexto?

Comment: Eu prefiro sempre buscar do banco a entidade, e no controller (no post) eu uso uma ViewModel.Já o método para adicionar no contexto é este mesmo (EntityState.Modified, ou Attach) e deveria ter funcionado se a entidade veio do model binder. O que pode ser também  é que vc está usando o mesmo contexto em todas as requisições (o contexto é estático?) o que é uma má prática também.

Comment: Ah ta, entendi. Valeu Fernando!  Mas o contexto não é estático. Não tem como marcar sua resposta aqui como resolvida?

Comment: pelos comentários não. Como você não colocou a outra parte do código (que instancia o contexto, e a entidade) eu não quis criar uma resposta. Se vc colocar o código, posso adicionar uma resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 1):

O seu update não está reconhecendo o objeto como um objeto já existente.
Eu tive o mesmo problema outras vezes, há dicas a respeito em um outro post.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201907/asp-net-mvc-attaching-an-entity-of-type-modelname-failed-because-another-ent

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa adicionar o `obj` no `DbSet<T>`

Exemplo:

```
public void AtualizarCliente(Cliente obj)
{
      banco.Cliente.Add(obj);//Você adiciona o obj modificado no cliente
      Atualizar(obj);//Agora você pode mandar salvar.
}
```